# Assign constant values to structs in C

Tags: c, constants

This is an array of structs with elements declared as `const`.
It is also passed as global in the header file using `extern` keyword.

```
// foo.h file
typedef enum
{
    A = 0,
    B,
    C,
    NAMES_MAX,
} Names_t;

typedef struct
{
    const int x;
    const int y;
} Foot_t;

// my global array.
extern const Foot_t FOO[NAMES_MAX];
```

```
// foo.c file
const Foot_t FOO[NAMES_MAX] =
{
    [A] = { .x = 1, .y = 1 },
    [B] = { .x = 2, .y = 2 },
    [C] = { .x = 3, .y = 3 },
};
```

I use the `Names_t` as index for the struct `FOO`.

Now I tried to use my global struct to assign a value to another struct.

```
// bar.c file
typedef struct
{
    const int x;
    const int y;
    // more members here.
} Bar_t;

static Bar_t BAR =
{
    .x = FOO[A].x,
    .y = FOO[A].y,
};
```

But I get an error `initializer element is not constant in C`.
I know what the error means, `FOO` is not actually a constant expression as it would be in C++.

The question is how can I resolve this error by maintain the structure above?

Comment: Why can't you use `FOO` directly where you currently have `BAR`?

Comment: Because bar contains more members. Thanks for the input. I edited my example

Comment: You might remove the ones from BAR and use both FOO and BAR then – or replace the values by `int const* const` pointers, these *can* be initialised ( `= &Foo[A].x` ) – though if the pointer indirection really is nicer appears questionable to me. You could as well `#define` the two values in question and use these for initialising all four variables.

Comment: This is a FAQ. You are essentially just asking why `static int x=0; static int y=x;` isn't possible. There's numerous duplicates, I can't be bothered to hunt one down.

Comment: C23 will add `constexpr` store specifier that would let one use `FOO` as compilation time constant

Answer (score 3):

Objects either declared at file scope or with the keyword `static`, i.e. those with *static storage duration*, must be initialized with a *constant expression*, and the value of another value (whether or not it is declared `const`) is not such an expression.  You'll need to initialize the values explicitly.

Also, it's not a good idea to declare members of a `struct` as `const`.  It can cause issues when you attempt to use the struct.  You're better off declaring specific instances as `const` rather than the members, i.e.:

```
typedef struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
}Foot_t;

const Foot_t FOO[NAMES_MAX] =
{
  [A] = { .x = 1, .y = 1},
  [B] = { .x = 2, .y = 2},
  [C] = { .x = 3, .y = 3},
};
```

Comment: Yes, I also have declared the struct `Foo_t` as `const` I forgot to add it in the example. Just added.

Comment: `You're better off declaring specific instances as const rather than the members, i.e.:` it is a very bad advice. It has to to be declared the way it fits the application. For example struct representing hardware register may have r/o members but the whole struct is not r/w

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not related to the `const` keyword as `FOO` is not a constant expression regardless if you add `const` or not.
I see two workarounds:

1. You use macros which *are* constant expressions to initialize both FOO and BAR.

```
// foo.h file
#define FOO_A_X (1)
//...
```

```
// foo.c file
const Foot_t FOO[NAMES_MAX] =
{
  [A] = { .x = FOO_A_X, .y = FOO_A_Y},
  [B] = { .x = FOO_B_X, .y = FOO_B_Y},
  [C] = { .x = FOO_C_X, .y = FOO_C_Y},
};
//...
```

```
// bar.c file
// ...
static Bar_t BAR =
{
  .x = FOO_A_X,
  .y = FOO_A_Y,
};
```

2. You initialize BAR at runtime, which is kind of hacky as you declared its members as const.

```
// bar.c file
// ...
#include <string.h>
static Bar_t BAR;

void Bar_Initializer(void)
{
   memcpy((void*)&BAR, &FOO[A], sizeof BAR);
}
```

Comment: "which is kind of hacky" Very hacky since memcpy into a const variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: Correct. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to define the `FOO` initializer constants:

```
#define FOO_A_x 1
#define FOO_A_y 2
...
```

and use these values for initializing both structs:

```
const Foot_t FOO[NAMES_MAX] =
{
  [A] = { .x = FOO_A_x, .y = FOO_A_y},
  ...
};

...

static Bar_t BAR =
{
  .x = FOO_A_x,
  .y = FOO_A_y,
};
```